# jQuery .on("click") event with exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

Hi I'm using a collapsible tree on a list i made. it uses jQuery to collapse the tree on click and there is an edit button next to it.

> What I want to do: I want to use a selector that removes the edit span from the  click function so that when I click on edit nothing happens but when I click on the  the tree collapses.

I want it to be something like:`$('.hotelsholder').on("click", "ul>li:not(span)", function (e)` but this won't work.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hotelsholder').on("click", "ul>li", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('changed');
    console.log(this);
    if ($(this).find("ul").first().css("display") === "none") {
      console.log('this' + $(this).find("ul").first().css("display"))
      $(this).children(":nth-child(2)").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hotelsholder>ul>li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.editHotel {
  color: blue;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hotelsholder">  
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      first level
      <span class="editHotel">edit</span>
      <ul style="display: block;">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: haow you can make a click in an htmlElement hidden?

Comment: function(e) has a target (click) just ask if this target is a span, Check console.log(e.target)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón i don't know what you mean can you make your question clearer?

Comment: @Roy i have tried that the function in on <li> which has a <span> inside it.

Comment: Check @Wouter Bouwman response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roy has stated in his comment, you can check wether the target is the span like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/o1cmb72d/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hotelsholder').on("click", "ul>li", function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('editHotel'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    console.log(e.target);
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).toggleClass('changed');
        console.log(this);
        if ($(this).find("ul").first().css("display") === "none") {
            console.log('this' + $(this).find("ul").first().css("display"))
            $(this).children(":nth-child(2)").slideDown();
        }
        else {
            $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't think of it that way thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a click function to your span that prevents propagation. EXPLANATION: the `span` is part of the `li` so when you click the span, you also click the `li`. Attaching its own function with stopPropagation prevents it to trigger the other function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hotelsholder').on("click", "ul>li", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).toggleClass('changed');
            console.log(this);
            if ($(this).find("ul").first().css("display") === "none") {
                console.log('this' + $(this).find("ul").first().css("display"))
                $(this).children(":nth-child(2)").slideDown();
            }
            else {
                $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
            }
        });
        $('.editHotel').on("click", function (e) {
             e.stopPropagation();
             console.log('edit link clicked');
        });
    });
```

```css
.hotelsholder>ul>li{cursor:pointer;}
.editHotel{color:blue; margin-left:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hotelsholder">  
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      first level
      <span class="editHotel">edit</span>
      <ul style="display: block;">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can try

```
$('.hotelsholder').on("click", ".editHotel", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is add a click handler for the `span`, and stop propagation. So when someone clicks on the `span`, the event won't propagate up to the containing `li`:

```
$('.hotelsholder').on("click", "ul>li>span", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```